# How to eliminate overlapping lines in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, svg, coordinates, path-finding

I have a list of lists of coordinates, each representing a path segment in an SVG path defined by two points, such that `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`. In some cases there will be smaller segments that are fully overlapped by another one in the list.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
segments = [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Represents segments in the following path, respectively:

[image: Line Example]

In this case, the first segment is fully overlapped by the last one and therefore `segments[0]` should be removed as it is inside `segments[4]`. A path can exceed 8,000 segments. **What would be the most efficient way of eliminating the smaller overlapping segments?**

#### UPDATE

These additional conditions further define this problem:

- Segments do not necessarily need to be along the `x` or `y` axes as in the example (i.e., a segment such as `[1, 1, 2, 2]` is also possible).
- If there is only a partial overlap (e.g., as would be seen between a pair of segments `[3, 1, 1, 1]` and `[2, 1, 4, 1]`), no segment is removed.

Comment: This is too broad, and is likely off-topic for Stack Overflow. Can you narrow it down to a specific technical problem? See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: That list doesn't look like SVG path.

Comment: Are the lines always orthogonal? For example, is `[1, 1, 2, 2]` possible? Also, are there cases where there is only partial overlap? For example, as would be seen with a pair of lines `[3, 1, 1, 1]` and `[2, 1, 4, 1]`?

Comment: *Segment overlap* is covered by [line segment intersection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection).

Comment: (You do realise that removing contained line-segments more often than not leaves the path not connected, don't you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simpler answer that captures all segments (orthogonal or not) and requires only a commonly accessible package, `NumPy` (and some basic geometry knowledge):

```py
import numpy as np

segments = [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]
# Function determines if segment between coordinates 1 & 2 completely overlaps
# the segment between coordinates 3 & 4
def completelyOverlaps(x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return (x1 <= x3 and x1 <= x4 and x2 >= x3 and x2 >= x4) or \
        (x2 <= x3 and x2 <= x4 and x1 >= x3 and x1 >= x4)

overlapped = []
for i in range(len(segments)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(segments)):
        [x1, y1, x2, y2] = segments[i]
        [x3, y3, x4, y4] = segments[j]
        # Checks whether the cross product between two different pairs of points
        # are both == 0, which means that the segments are both on the same line
        if np.cross(np.array([x1-x2, y1-y2]), np.array([x3-x4, y3-y4])) == 0 and \
            np.cross(np.array([x1-x2, y1-y2]), np.array([x3-x1, y3-y1])) == 0:
            # If lines are vertical, consider the y-coordinates
            if x1 == x2:
                # If 1st segment fully overlaps 2nd, add latter to the list
                if completelyOverlaps(y1, y2, y3, y4):
                    overlapped.append(segments[j])
                # If 2nd segment fully overlaps 1st, add latter to the list
                elif completelyOverlaps(y3, y4, y1, y2):
                    overlapped.append(segments[i])
            # In all other cases, consider the x-coordinates
            else:
                if completelyOverlaps(x1, x2, x3, x4):
                    overlapped.append(segments[j])
                elif completelyOverlaps(x3, x4, x1, x2):
                    overlapped.append(segments[i])

segments = [s for s in segments if s not in overlapped]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
print(segments)

> [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: You have to handle partial overlap, e.g. [[2, 1, 4, 1], [3,1,6,1]]. Output of this should be same as input.

Comment: Have you actually tried running it? The output is as stated. Moreover, see on the OP: “If there is only partial overlap, no segment is removed.”

Comment: yes I have executed it. I really liked the logic. But the partial overlap is not being handled, I think you have to do some changes in code.

Comment: See my previous comment edited and the second bullet point in the OP’s “UPDATE”.

Comment: No brother, Give this  [[2, 1, 4, 1], [3,1,6,1]] as input and output gives only one segment.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant and you were correct. I have edited the code to account for that and it should now work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204306/discussion-between-brunox13-and-vinod-sawant).

Answer (score -1):

## Update:

This approach is by using library and is fully functional and solves entire problem, and older approach is with custom algorithm but that does not take inclined segments into consideration.

Google colab link for code, in case you get any error in installing library.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tcQ5gps8dQz9kNY93rfAK97hSQPjCvOt

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
lines = [[1, 1, 1, 2],[2, 1, 4, 1],[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]
overlaped_lines = []
for i in lines:
  for j in lines:
    if j == i:
      continue
    if LineString([(i[0],i[1]),(i[2],i[3])]).within(LineString([(j[0],j[1]),(j[2],j[3])])):
      overlaped_lines.append(i)
      break

for i in overlaped_lines:
  lines.remove(i)

print(lines)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 4, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]
```

## Previous approach,

works only for lines which are parallel to x or y axis, but not for inclined lines.

### I have worked on it in the following way,

```
def find_overlap(lines):
    l = []
    i = 0
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines:
        j=0
        for xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2 in lines:
            if j == i:
                j+=1
                continue
            #Check for lines along x-axis    
            if (y2-y1) == 0 and (yy2-yy1) == 0 and y1 == yy1 and y2 == yy2:
                a,b,c,d = min(xx1,xx2), max(xx1,xx2), min(x1,x2),max(x1,x2)
                if c >= a and d <= b:
                    l.append(lines[i])
                    break
            #Check for lines along y-axis         
            if (x2-x1) == 0 and (xx2-xx1) == 0 and x1 == xx1 and x2 == xx2:
                a,b,c,d = min(yy1,yy2), max(yy1,yy2), min(y1,y2),max(y1,y2)
                if c >= a and d <= b:
                    l.append(lines[i])
                    break   
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return l

def remove_overlap(l,lines):
    for i in l:
        lines.remove(i)
    return lines

lines = [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2],[3, 4, 3, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]

l = find_overlap(lines)
lines_after_overlap_removal = remove_overlap(l,lines)
```

### Output:

```
lines
Out[19]: [[1, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2],[3, 4, 3, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1]]

lines_after_overlap_removal
Out[20]: [[2, 1, 2, 2], [3, 4, 3, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2], [3, 1, 1, 1]]
```

### Explanation:

1) First for loop parses through the given list, lets consider this example for i = 0,
lines[0] = [1, 1, 2, 1]

2) Second for loop checks other coordinates which are along x and y axis

e.g. :

first for loop has [1, (y1)1, 2, (y2)1] which is along x axis i.e. parallel to x axis, as y1 = y2.

Now second for loop brings me the element [2, (yy1)1, 2, (yy2)2] , here y1 == yy1 but y2 != yy2

next it goes on and at last it brings [3, 1, 1, 1], where y1 == yy1 and y2 == yy2.

Now lets check whether its x co-ordinates overlap or not, as the co-ordinates can be in reverse order we will have to make them forward for our interpretation,
e.g. : coordinate that goes from 3 to 1 which is equal to 1 to 3.
this is done with simple operation of finding min and max from list.

then check forwarded x1,x2 with xx1,xx2 and if they overlap then make a note of it in list l. i.e. append it to list l.
Now last step that will be to remove elements that overlap, which is done by last function remove_overlap.

Comment: Can you use better variable names?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I am kind of "getting work done" person, So did not focus on the design aspect. Could you please suggest best edit possible? That would be really great and addition to my knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: I find the conditions checked to detect overlap confusing: even if segments were iso-oriented (as indicated by the comments added in revision 2), checking given `y1 == yy1 and y2 == yy2` is true for segments that are neither parallel to the x-axis nor collinear, too: `[[1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 2]]`. Furthermore, each and every condition in the overlap checks is symmetrical: there is no way of knowing which of two segments is *not* contained in the other one and should be kept.

Comment: Hi,@greybeard, I have not yet handled inclined lines condition in update. I have only handled sengments which are parallel to x or y axis, It can remove fully overlapped segments, and it will not remove partially overlapped segments.

Comment: @greybeard, I got what you are saying about condition check about parallelism to x or y axis.